# could not insert values in oracle through procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a procedure, which inserts three values into a table. However, when I try to insert values, no value get inserted.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTPRODUCTRECORD9 (p_PNAME IN VARCHAR2, p_CATEGORY IN VARCHAR2, p_PRICE IN NUMBER) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO PRODUCT (PNAME,PRICE,CATEGORY) VALUES(p_PNAME, p_CATEGORY, p_PRICE); 
END;

begin
    INSERTPRODUCTRECORD9('TAB','GADGETS',30000);
END;
```

Comment: it seems that you have a wrong order of the fields in your insert

Comment: You are inserting p_category in the price column and p_price in the category column. Please correct your INSERT statement and confirm whether it is still failing. Also, do share the error which you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert` statement has the columns listed in a different order than the values; so you are probably trying to insert a `VARCHAR2` into a `NUMBER` field.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTPRODUCTRECORD9 (p_PNAME IN VARCHAR2, p_CATEGORY IN VARCHAR2, p_PRICE IN NUMBER) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO PRODUCT (PNAME,CATEGORY,PRICE) VALUES(p_PNAME, p_CATEGORY, p_PRICE ); 
END;

begin
    INSERTPRODUCTRECORD9('TAB','GADGETS',30000);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The COMMIT keyword may be rquired too

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTPRODUCTRECORD9 (p_PNAME IN VARCHAR2, p_CATEGORY IN VARCHAR2, p_PRICE IN NUMBER) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO PRODUCT (PNAME,PRICE,CATEGORY) VALUES(p_PNAME, p_PRICE,     p_CATEGORY ); 
COMMIT;
END;

begin
    INSERTPRODUCTRECORD9('TAB','GADGETS',30000);
END;
```

Comment: It's not good practice to commit in a procedure, generally. The topmost caller should decide when a transaction starts and end. If the anonymous block called the procedure twice and the second one failed, there would be no way to roll back to a consistent state.

Comment: after correcting order and adding commit statement,success with compilation error message appears.